# Django adminplus doesn't go to custom views

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to install django adminplus: https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus

Here is my urls.py for the site:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from adminplus.sites import AdminSitePlus
from django.conf.urls import include, url

admin.site = AdminSitePlus()
admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

Here is my admin view:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
admin.site.register_view('somepath', view=my_view)
```

Here is my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'smart_selects',
    'adminplus',
)
```

When I go to example.com/somepath I get a 404 error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus):

> Now my_view will be accessible at **admin/somepath** and there will be a link to it in the Custom Views section of the admin index.

Does your url show up on the 404 page?